# Problems "commiting" with new version of TortoiseHG

Tags: tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

I've just upgraded to **TortoiseHG 2.0** (which has a brand new GUI) on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

When I *right-click* a modified file and select `Hg Commit . . .` from the context menu, I get a "No files found for this operation" error message popping up.  The selected file has the correct, "modified" icon, and if select the file from within the new Workbench, I am able to successfully commit it.

Any suggestions for fixing the problem with Committing from the right-click context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `Hg Status` on the whole directory, or even a `Hg Update`.

If the commit still don't work, I think you have found a bug in TortoiseHG and you should report it to the dev team.

Comment: status correctly shows the modified files, but the commit won't work from the right-click context menu.  It DOES work from the new Workbench application.

Comment: just discovered a reply from a posting I made to the TortoiseHG list:Hmm, looks like there is a bug here.  As a workaround you can click on the 'Remove filter, show root' button at the bottom of the file list.

Comment: I have the same problem with 2.0.0-hg-1.8-x64. Can you add the link the TortoiseHG list discussion? I hope the bug is fixed

Comment: It is fixed in tortoisehg-2.0.4-hg-1.8.3-x64